# Not identifying custom cmdlets when the batch file to launch a powershell script is invoked through a window service

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I've a Powershell script which consists of custom cmdlets which are stored in Powershell profiles.
I made a batch file to invoke that script which will look like this:

```
powershell.exe C:\MyScript.ps1 -remoteMachinesList ABC123,ABC456 -TestServer xxx.xxx.xx.xxx -TestVersion 3.7
```

When I run this batch file normally(by double clicking), the script runs properly identifying the custom cmdlets used in the script.

But when I invoke the same via a windows service, the batch file is invoked, which in turn launches the powershell script and it says the term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, funtion, script file, ... and it closes the window. I'm able to see the GUI because I'm calling the cmd.exe application using 'StartProcessAndBypassUAC' in the windows service.

What's the difference it makes here so that it is not identifying the custom cmdlets? I can see that both ways opens the cmds and powershell windows in admin mode itself.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried sourcing the psm1 cmdlets by their fully qualified paths within MyScript.ps1?

Comment: @rojo No I didn't, since I thought it will automatically take it from the default profile path. Will it not take it from there, otherwise how did it took when I run the batch file manually ?

Comment: It sounds like the context of the Windows service doesn't have the same path as when you double click the script.  You can either fully qualify the paths of your module includes, or try changing the account under which the service runs as your user account.

Comment: @rojo Thanks very much, can you please elaborate on how to do those two things suggested.

Comment: Not sure what *PowerShell Profile* is. Are your referring to `$Profile`? Maybe you're referring to the `$env:PSModulePath`?